# Extract keys and values from XML in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xml-parsing

I receive XML data like

```
<t>
  <ID>8</ID>
  <FirstName>name 8</FirstName>
  <LastName>surname 8</LastName>
  <DateOfBirth>1963-05-23T00:00:00</DateOfBirth>
</t>
```

In a SQL Server stored procedure. There are different xml data formats (the field numbers and field names can differ). Now, I should extract each field and it value and insert each field/value as a separate record in a table.

Are there examples how I can do this with TSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily scan the XML - if it's always under a `<t>` root node and always just one level deep:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<t>
  <ID>8</ID>
  <FirstName>name 8</FirstName>
  <LastName>surname 8</LastName>
  <DateOfBirth>1963-05-23T00:00:00</DateOfBirth>
</t>'

SELECT
    FieldName = nodes.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'),
    FieldValue = nodes.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @input.nodes('/t/*') AS Tbl(nodes)
```

Output is:

[image]

But it really depends on what you want to do with that data now - once you've retrieved it from the XML .... what does the structure of your intended target table look like?

Comment: thank you very much. That is exactly what I am looking for. I have to save each key/value in one record in my target table. Grüsse von St. Gallen nach Bern ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Where `@x` is your xml

```
insert yourtable (ID, Firstname, Lastname, DOB)
select 
    @x.value('(/t/ID)[1]','int'),
    @x.value('(/t/FirstName)[1]','varchar(50)'),
    @x.value('(/t/LastName)[1]','varchar(50)'),
    @x.value('(/t/DateOfBirth)[1]','datetime')
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030(v=sql.100).aspx